# How to keep track of call statistics? C++

Tags: c++, class, static, statistics

I'm working on a project that delivers statistics to the user. I created a class called Dog,
And it has several functions. Speak, woof, run, fetch, etc.

I want to have a function that spits out how many times each function has been called. I'm also interested in the constructor calls and destructor calls as well.

I have a header file which defines all the functions, then a separate .cc file that implements them. My question is, is there a way to keep track of how many times each function is called?

I have a function called print that will fetch the "statistics" and then output them to standard output. I was considering using static integers as part of the class itself, declaring several integers to keep track of those things. I know the compiler will create a copy of the integer and initialize it to a minimum value, and then I'll increment the integers in the .cc functions.

I also thought about having static integers as a global variable in the .cc. Which way is easier? Or is there a better way to do this?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You could have local variables that increment each time a method is called.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using static member variables is the way to go. However, the compiler will not "create a copy of the integer and initialize it to a minimum value"; you'll have to provide a definition for each one in the .cc file and initialize it to 0 there. (Things are a bit different if you're using C++11, but the basic idea is the same.)

There's no reason to use static global variables instead of static members.

foo.h:

```
class Foo {
  static int countCtor_;
  static int countDtor_;
  static int countprint_:
  Foo();
  ~Foo();
  static void print();
};
```

foo.cc:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "foo.h"

int Foo::countCtor_ = 0;
int Foo::countDtor_ = 0;
int Foo::countprint_ = 0;

Foo::Foo() {
  ++countCtor_;
  // Something here
}
Foo::~Foo() {
  ++countDtor_;
  // Something here
}
void Foo::print() {
  ++countprint_;
  std::cout << "Ctor:  " << countCtor_ << "\n"
            << "Dtor:  " << countDtor_ << "\n"
            << "print: " << countprint_ << "\n";
}
```

But if you've got a lot of functions, the repetition involved is a bit annoying—it's very easy to accidentally do ++countBar_ when you meant ++countBaz_ (especially if you copy and paste the boilerplate), so you may want something a bit fancier, such as a static map and a macro that increments counts[__FUNC__], so you can just use the exact same line in each function. Like this:

foo.h:

```
#include <map>
class Foo {
  static std::map<const char*, int> counts_;
  Foo();
  ~Foo();
  void print();
};
```

foo.cc:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "foo.h"

std::map<const char *, int> Foo::counts_;

#define INC_COUNT_() do { ++counts_[__FUNC__]; } while (0)

Foo::Foo() {
  INC_COUNT_();
  // Something here
}
Foo::~Foo() {
  INC_COUNT_();
  // Something here
}
void Foo::print() {
  INC_COUNT_();
  for (std::map<const char *, int>::const_iterator it = counts_.begin(); 
       it != counts_.end(); ++it) {
    std::cout << it->first << ": " << it->second << "\n";
  }
}
```

In the example code above, __FUNC__ is a placeholder. Unfortunately, there is no standard-compliant value you can use in its place. Most compilers have some subset of __func__, __FUNC__, __FUNCTION__, __FUNCSIG__, and __PRETTY_FUNCTION__. However, none of those are standard in C++03. C++11 does standardize __func__, but only as an "implementation-defined string", which isn't guaranteed to be useful, or even unique. On top of that, the values will be different on different compilers. Also, some of them may be macros rather than identifiers, to make things more fun.

If you want truly portable code, in C++11, you can use something like string(__func__) + ":" + STRINGIZE(__LINE__)—this will be somewhat ugly, but at least each function will have a unique name. And in C++03, there is no equivalent. If you just need "portable enough", consult the documentation for every compiler you use, or rely on something like autoconf.

Comment: I can't figure out why the first foo.cc's formatting is screwed up. I've tried it with four spaces in each blank line, and with actual blank lines, and either way, some of the lines don't show up as code…

Comment: I am unaware of `__FUNC__`, but I am assuming you mean the standard `__func__`. However, you should really use the decorated name of the function so that overloaded function names are counted separately.

Comment: Sorry, you're right; just because something is both a MSVC extension and a gcc extension doesn't mean it's standard. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply! Glad to see I got the static member variables part right, even though the compiler stuff wrong. :) Do you know of a good resource to learn more about static members?

Comment: If you aren't sure you already know the basics, any good C++ tutorial or textbook should explain things. If you want to know the exact details of the definition, I don't know anything better than the standard (which is hard reading); maybe someone else can help. However, Stroustrop's two books may explain things for ancient C++, and things haven't changed much since then for static members.

Comment: @abarnert although, what if this were to change where i had helper functions in the .cc that needed to access the static variable members in the Dog class? I forgot to mention that I have different functions in the .cc that will also need access to the static members in Dog. :)

Comment: @abarnert I'll be sure to dig in to those books, could use some hard material. Thanks!

Comment: The access rules for static members are identical to for non-static members. A public static member can be accessed by anyone; a protected one by Dog, its subclasses, and its friends; a private one only by Dog and its friends. The only difference is that a single value is shared by all instances of the class (it's basically a global variable in disguise), instead of each instance having its own.

Answer (score 3):

Is there any reason you can't use standard profiling tools that will count these calls for you? Something like [gprof](http://www.cs.utah.edu/dept/old/texinfo/as/gprof_toc.html)?

Otherwise static integers would be the way to go.

Comment: The first half of this answer is good, but the second half is not. Putting static integers inside the methods themselves leaves him no way to create the "print" function he describes (or any other way to access the values, outside a debugger).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want these statistics tracked all the time in your program, you could use an `unordered_map` of your function names:

```
std::unordered_map<const char *, unsigned> stats;

void foo () {
    // use __FUNCDNAME__ for MSVC
    ++stats[__PRETTY_FUNCTION__];
    //...
}
```

The use of compiler specific function name specifiers is purposefully there to get the decorated function names. This is so that overloaded function names get counted as separate functions.

This technique allows you to add new functions easily without thinking about anything else, but there is a small additional cost if there are hash collisions (which can be remedied somewhat by sizing the `stats` map to be larger). There is no hash computed on the string, since the key is a pointer type, it just uses the pointer value itself as the hash.

If this is just one-off code for profiling, then you should first try to use the code profiling tools available on your platform.

Comment: +1. Although the focus on micro-optimizing efficiency seems a bit misguided, it's still much simpler and easier to read than my very similar answer.

Comment: @abarnert: Thanks for the upvote. If the purpose of the question is simply an information gathering exercise, then I agree that efficiency should not be a concern. But, in a performance sensitive application, it is always nice if the solution is both clean and efficient. Regards

Comment: Actually, I suspect map has a good chance of being more efficient than unordered_map for the expected tiny values of N: log 10 may be faster than hashing a string, and 3*10 may be smaller than the default starting size for the hash table. It's also quicker to write and read—in particular, when I see unordered_map, I wonder why that was chosen over map. Also, it'll be much more predictable across compilers, runs, and minor changes to the code. And, best of all, it works with C++98.

Comment: @abarnert: There is no hashing of the string, the pointer value itself is used as the hash. The only compute is the modulo for the number of buckets in the `unordered_map`. The only time there is a slow down is if there is a collision, which won't happen if the number of functions is as small as you say.

Comment: I honestly wouldn't try to predict without measuring which one is faster or smaller without measuring on each compiler. But unless it makes a difference, I wouldn't bother measuring; I'd put C++98 compatibility, predictability, even brevity way ahead of performance. Of course if he's got 5000 methods in his class… well, then he needs to refactor the class, and probably write a code generator instead of relying on cpp…

Comment: @abarnert: In my job, I have to consider everything, including performance. Regards

Comment: Sure, I have to consider performance too. But I do that by finding the hotspots and optimizing them, not by micro-optimizing random lines of code without even measuring.

Comment: @abarnert: That is how to optimize, but I am still expected to make a reasonably good decision. If the "micro-optimized" version is just as easy to understand, and just as easy to implement as the "non-micro-optimized" version, then that is the route I take. Regards

Answer (score 1):

You can put `static` locals inside the methods themselves, that seems cleaner since these variables aren't logically connected to the class so there's no reason to make them members.

Additionaly, you could have a macro to simplify the work. I normally don't recommend using macros, but this seems like an appropriate use:

```
#define DEFINE_COUNTER \
   static int noCalls = 0; \
   noCalls++;


void foo()
{
   DEFINE_COUNTER
}
```

Comment: How is his print function going to fetch the statistics if he does things this way?

Comment: @abarnert several options - global `map` that is modified by the macro, call the function with the number as parameter...

Comment: If there's a global map modified by the macro, then what are the function-local statics for?

Comment: @abarnert that's a different approach. Not enough of a reason for a downvote, but whatever...

Comment: The answer you gave doesn't answer the user's question. You then said that you could add a solution that does actually work, which is true, but in that case your answer doesn't add anything to just using that other solution in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Use a library that implements the Observer Pattern or Method Call Interception.  You can choose one from [this list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern#C.2B.2B), or use something like [Vitamin](http://unseenstudios.com/karlgluck/2010/07/vitamin-a-cpp-method-call-interceptor-library/).